# Guava cache - key is composite , need to query by first key and get a list

Tags: java, caching

I have requirement where I need to store data with a composite/multiple keys , but query only by  first key and get a list of records.
Assume the composite key consisting of 3 filelds key1, key2 and key3. When it is queried by key1, it should check the cache if there any records matching with key1 and if not query the database with the first key , get multiple records and store the records ( with composite key) in the cache and return them to the user.

How do I do this in Guava? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store them in that Guava cache based on the composite key, because you don't search with composite key.

Cache only the query result in Guava and handle the split of the result after you resolved the value from the cache. Store a list of objects (rows) as value in the Guava cache (list instead of single object).